# error with ssziparchive

Tags: ios, objective-c, ssziparchive

I would like to export a ZIP file it is a sound file.

Then I would like to control this sound file using Push Notification.

When I load the sound file directly into Xcode it works. However, I export the file using a ZIP file it does not find the file?

As if he then does not find the file? What am I doing wrong?

I suspect the error is here: `toDestination:@""`

https://github.com/soffes/ssziparchive

[image: structure]

```
- (IBAction)sound_ko:(id)sender {
    //File check...

    NSBundle *mainBundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
    NSString *myFile = [mainBundle pathForResource: @"KO" ofType: @"zip"];

    BOOL fileExists2 = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:myFile];
    if (fileExists2 == NO){
        NSLog(@"DOESNT Exist!");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"DOES Exist!");
    }

    //Unzip File
    if( [SSZipArchive unzipFileAtPath:myFile toDestination:@""] != NO ) {
        NSLog(@"Dilip Success");
    }else{
        NSLog(@"Dilip Error");
    }
}
```

Comment: This has precisely **nothing** to do with Xcode. -- anyway, you better specify a real, **writable** location to unzip the file.

Answer (score 1):

There is a method that you can pass an error pointer to receive some more info in swift use this:

```
SSZipArchive.unzipFileAtPath(libAssetPath.path, toDestination: libSupportPath.path, overwrite: true, password: nil, error: &err, delegate: self)

                if(err != nil){
                    print("\(err.debugDescription)")
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure to write on a writable location. Probably the best place to extract the file would be the Temp folder.